# $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ is not Dedekind?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

I am considering the following example, but confused to convince that it is not Dedekind.

> The ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]=\{ a+b\sqrt{5}:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is not Dedekind, because it is not integrally closed in its field of Fractions.

*Justification.* The field of fractions of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ is $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{5}]$, and the element $(1+\sqrt{5})/2$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ but it is not in this domain, hence this domain is not integrally closed.

**Q.1** Is above fact correct with this justification?

If yes, then I have next question. It is known that the quotient of a Dedekind domain by a proper non-zero ideal is [Edited] **Principal ideal ring** (not necessarily domain-pointed out in answer.)

**Q.2** What is the non-zero proper ideal $I$ of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ such that quotient is not *principal ideal ring*?

---

**Edit:** The following is an exercise from Isaacs' Algebra. This is reference for Q.2.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: Sorry; there was misplacing of minus sign in initial post. It is corrected now.

Comment: You've gotten an example in an answer, but be careful: as you have worded it, the "quotient by a proper ideal is a principal ideal ring"-property is something that Dedekind domains have, but not something that characterizes them. In other words, there may be rings which have that property but aren't Dedekind domains. So a priori, the answer to Q2 may be "There are none".

Comment: I think, *domains* having the property ("..quotient is principal ideal ring..") are Dedekind domains; I inserted reference; whereas, for general *rings* you may be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1: you are correct.

Q2: the quotient of a Dedekind domain by a proper nonzero ideal is in general not a domain, let alone a PID. Are you confusing quotients with
localisations?

[Added after OP's edit]

Try $I=(4)$.

Comment: Thanks for noticing my error; I am sorry for confusion with not carefully noting the fact. I edited question.